# The ideal of polynomials vanishing over Gaussian integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field. Let $S \subset k^n$.

Define $I(S)=\{f\in k[x_1,...,x_n]~|~f(a_1,...,a_n)=0~ \forall ~(a_1,...,a_n)\in S\}$.

It is known that $I(S)$ is an ideal.

Let $\mathbb{Z}^n$ be the set of points of $\mathbb{C}^n$ with integer coordinates.

I want to determine $I(\mathbb{Z}^n)$. I have no idea where to start on this. Please give a generous hint, but refrain from giving full solution, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamHughes. I do not think this is an easy problem.

Comment: @lukeskywalker: It's not actually that hard.  If you can't get it from my hint then ask all I'll nudge you further.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** If $f \in I(\mathbb Z^n)$ then for any $a_2, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb Z$ we have that $f(x, a_2, \ldots, a_n) \in \mathbb C[x]$ vanishes on $\mathbb Z$.